# Is $\frac{1}{6}\ln(x+4)^6$ equivalent to $\ln(x+4)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I was doing a question and was wondering if bringing the coefficient back into the exponent was allowed?

So, for example: $$\frac{1}{6}\ln(x+4)^6$$

Is it possible for me to do:
$$\ln(x+4)$$

Are those two equivalent?

I am struggling on what to do because I am doing a question where it is asking me to simplify to a single logarithm:
$$\frac{1}{6}\ln(x+4)^6 + \frac{1}{4}[\ln x-\ln(x^2+6x+8)^4]$$

If I can put them back into the exponent area, then I could do something such as:
$$\ln(x+4)+\ln x^\frac{1}{4}-\ln(x^2+6x+8)$$

After that, I could apply the basic adding and subtracting rules to get: $$\ln\left(\frac{(x+4)x^\frac{1}{4}}{x^2+6x+8}\right)$$

Finally, I could factor the bottom and reduce the numerator and denominator: $$\ln\left(\frac{(x+4)x^\frac{1}{4}}{(x+4)(x+2)}\right)$$

$$\ln\left(\frac{x^\frac{1}{4}}{x+2}\right)$$

Is this way of thinking right or am I not allowed to put the exponent back into the exponent area?

Comment: if they are not then how would I simplify this question into a single logarithmic?

Comment: Actually, your notation is quite ambiguous. Does $\frac16\ln(x+4)^6$ denote $\frac16\ln\left((x+4)^6\right)$? Because if so then they are equivalent. However, do note that $\frac16\ln\left((x+4)^6\right)$ can take values of $x$ less than $-4$ while $\ln(x+4)$ cannot.

Comment: @Username generally speaking and if understood correctly what you are asking , if the exponent is an odd number you can but if the exponent is an even you have to put absolute values.For example $\ln(x+4)^6=6ln{\vert(x+4)\vert}$

Comment: If it has not been explicitly stated that $x > 0,$ nevertheless that is a necessary condition for $\ln x$ to be defined, so I think you can safely assume $x > 0$ (otherwise the original formula would have no value). That simplifies a lot of your other calculations because then $x+4>0$ and $x+2>0,$ so you can get away without the absolute value function. But you should be aware of how this works, and probably (since you had to ask this question) you should state facts like that in writing as you work through a problem like this.

Comment: It is not clear whether $\frac 16\ln (x+4)^6$ is supposed to be $\frac 16\ln [(x+4)^6]$ or if it's supposed to be $\frac 16 [\ln(x+4)]^6$.  Very different concepts.

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at some examples.  For the purposes of this discussion, all logarithms are natural (i.e., base $e$) and all logarithms are defined as functions from real numbers to the real numbers.

Consider $$f(x) = \frac{1}{6} \log (x+4)^6.$$  If $x = 0$, then we have $f(0) = \frac{1}{6} \log 4^6 = \log 4$.  But we can also choose values for which $x+4 < 0$; e.g., $$f(-5) = \frac{1}{6} \log (-5+4)^6 = \frac{1}{6} \log(-1)^6 = \frac{1}{6} \log 1 = 0.$$  In fact, the only real number for which $f(x)$ is not defined is $x = -4$.  This happens because raising $x+4$ to the sixth power always gives a nonnegative number, and in particular, a strictly positive number unless $x = -4$.

However, consider $$g(x) = \log (x+4).$$ Now if $x > -4$, we are okay because $x+4 > 0$.  But we run into problems if $x < -4$, since without the benefit of raising $x+4$ to the sixth power, it can be negative; e.g., $$g(-5) = \log(-5 + 4) = \log(-1).$$

So clearly, $f(x) \ne g(x)$ in all cases.  We do have equality if $x > -4$, but when $x < -4$, $f$ remains well-defined but $g$ does not.  To remedy this problem, we can write instead

$$h(x) = \log |x+4|,$$

and here, $f(x) = h(x)$ for all real numbers $x$ except $x = -4$, in which case neither $f$ nor $h$ are well-defined.

This suggests a path forward for your problem:  we have

$$\frac{1}{6} \log(x+4)^6  + \frac{1}{4} \left( \log x - \log (x^2 + 6x + 8)^4 \right) = \log|x+4| + \log x^{1/4} - \log |x^2 + 6x + 8|.$$  Note that we do not have to write $\log |x|^{1/4}$ (and in fact this would be incorrect), because the original function, $\frac{1}{4} \log x$, is defined if and only if $x > 0$ in the first place.  But this also means that $x+4 > 0$ and $x^2 + 6x + 8 > 0$, so it is actually the restriction imposed by $\log x$ that allows us to remove the absolute values on the other terms without loss of generality.  This gives us

$$\begin{align}\log (x+4) - \log(x^2 + 6x + 8) + \log x^{1/4} &= \log(x+4) - \log(x+4) - \log(x+2) + \log x^{1/4} \\&= \log x^{1/4} - \log (x+2) \\&= \log \frac{\sqrt[4]{x}}{x+2},\end{align}$$ where we require $x > 0$.

Keeping track of when expressions remain well-defined is an important part of simplifying algebraic expressions.

Plot of $\frac{1}{6} \log(x+4)^6 + \frac{1}{4}\left(\log x - log(x^2 + 6x + 8)^4\right)$:

[image]

Plot of $\log \frac{\sqrt[4]{x}}{x+2}$:

[image]

Comment: Ah so I should always check when x is defined within the functions. I will keep that in mind from now on. I also had a quick question, when I graph both functions in desmos, and they give me different graphs, I feel like that is not supposed to happen since we have only simplified the equation

Comment: @Username The plots I generated look equivalent to me.